# Why is proteinase K digestion performed at 50 °C?

Tags: dna-isolation, protocol

Many DNA isolation protocols use a [Proteinase K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteinase_K) digestion to remove proteins. This is often performed at 50 °C. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proteinase K activity is greatly increased by addition of denaturing agents like SDS or urea ([Hilz et al., 2008](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1975.tb02211.x/abstract)), indicating that the denaturation of the substrates helps Proteinase K to degrade them.

Increasing the temperature to 50°C will also unfold some proteins already, making it easier for the Proteinase K to degrade them. The proteinase K seems to be a pretty stable enzyme, and  can still work at this temperature.

Answer (score 2):

In your linked wiki article: "An elevation of the reaction temperature from 37 °C to 50 - 60 °C may increase the activity (of Proteinase K) several times." The enzyme works faster at 50°C.

Comment: some proteins are deactivated at that temperature... they are all different, aren't they?

Comment: @shigeta yup, they are all different.